# Find the tight bound of f(n)=3logN + 1 + (1/2) + (1/2)^2 + ... + (1/2)^n

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

This is for analysis of algorithms and I cannot seem to understand where to get started, how do i approach this to find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the sum of series `S = 1 + 1/2 + 1/2^2 + ... + 1/2^n` is constant,`f(n) = Theta(n)`.

We know that `S = (1 - 1/2^(n+1)) / (1 - 1/2)` and `n` goes to infinity `S` goes to `2`. Hence, limit of `f(n)` with grows of `n` is `3 log(n) + 2`.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of *1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + … + 1/2<sup>n</sup>* is constant. Indeed, this is a [*gemetric progression* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). The sum of:

```
 n
---
\     1
/    ----
---   2n
i=0
```

is the same as 2-1/2<sup>n</sup>, if *n* goes to infinity, the sum will eventually go to 2 (not infinity).

This thus means that *3×log(n) + 1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + … + 1/2<sup>n</sup>* is equivalent to 3×log(n)+2-1/2<sup>n</sup>. For an asymptotic *n*, this is thus equivalent to *Θ(3×* log *n)* and thus *Θ(* log *n)*.